# How to import a SSL certificate file with SWT Browser

Tags: java, browser, ssl, swt

With SWT Browser, is there any way to import a SSL certificate file into Java and make it work with SWT Browser?

With Firefox, you can import it by Edit-Preferences-Advanced-Encryption-View Certificates-Import command, but since Mozilla doesn't share profile with each other, we are not able to reuse that.

Is there any way? Any advices? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT Browser is just a component to display web pages using one of the engines. There is no extra-compatibility.

Certificates are managed differently on each platform & browser. There is no single-crossplatform interface to import certs. You have to find/develop a way to import certificate using other tools than SWT Browser component.

For example on Windows, you have to look how to import certificate on Windows using Java, probably use some command-line tools like mmc.

In other words you have to find special browser-based interface to import certs.