# SWT-Browser: How to load a resource using HTTPS if the certificate is untrusted?

Tags: java, https, swt, xulrunner

I am using the SWT Browser Widget to load the image of a webcam-server via HTTPS. Sadly the webcam-server certificate is untrusted. I tried to 2 variants to load the image:

1. `Browser.setHTML(String)`
   Load the image using HTML+JavaScript every second. This is the prefered way to avoid flickering. This works very fine for HTTP, if i have a HTTPS connection i will see noting at all except my alternative text.
2. `Browser.setUrl(String)`
   Load the image by setting the URL every second. This causes massiv flickering because of the reload, wich is unacceptable. I tried this variant with all available SWT-Browsers. If i use `SWT.WEBKIT` or `SWT.MOZILLA` (XulRunner) i have no chance at all to get the image. An dialog pop up and tell me the certificate is untrusted with no option to accept it. If i use `SWT.NONE` the IE is used (i am on WinXP) and the pop-up dialog ask if i want to trust the cert, after pressing OK i can see the image.

Here at Stackoverflow i found: [how-to-import-a-ssl-certificate-file-with-swt-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776875/how-to-import-a-ssl-certificate-file-with-swt-browser).
But i unable to find the [cert_override.txt](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Cert_override.txt) in my XULRunner, and i am unable to find a download link for the [Personal Security Manager](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/psm/) (like many others) !

How can i allow the untrusted certificate, use variant 1 and XULRunner aka MOZILLA ? Is it possible to do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cert_override.txt` is located in the user's profile. On Windows the directory for XULRunner's user profiles is `%APPDATA%\<vendor>\<product>\Profiles\<something>.default`, on OS X `/Library/Application Support/<product>/Profiles/<something>.default`, on Linux `~/.<vendor>/<product>/Profiles/<something>.default`. At runtime you can [use nsIDirectoryService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsIDirectoryService) to locate the directory (`ProfD` is the key for this directory).

You can either write to the user's profile directly from your application or add a copy of `cert_override.txt` to your XULRunner application to be copied into all user profiles created (it would have to be put under `defaults/profile/cert_override.txt` in the XULRunner application directory). Note that the latter will only have an effect on new profiles being created, not on profiles that already exist.

Btw, the simplest way to create a `cert_override.txt` file would be accepting an untrusted certificate in Firefox and then copying the entry from the Firefox profile to the XULRunner profile.

Comment: The application directory for the SWT-Browser (Windows) is: `..\Documents\<Username>\applicationdata\Mozilla\eclipse`.